# How to define {0} as regex in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using below regex pattern and its working fine

```
temp.replace(new RegExp(/\{1\}/g), +row.cells[0].innerText);
```

but now i wants to make the pattern dynamic but its not working.

```
for (i = 0; i < row.cells.length; i++) {
     temp = temp.replace(new RegExp("/\{"+i+"\}/g"), +row.cells[0].innerText);
}
```

Comment: strings have their own escape, you need to double escape in the `RegExp` constrcuctor.

Comment: I have tried so many combinations , could you please help.

Comment: but pls dont tell me its the type @ `+row.cells[0].innerText` what's the problem

Comment: The problem was regex, i was trying ```"/\{"+i+"\}/g"```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let strings = ["bli", "bla", "blueh", "foo", "bar"];

let temp = "{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}";
for (i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
     temp = temp.replace(new RegExp("\\{"+ (i + 1)+"\\}", "g"), strings[i]);
     console.log(temp);
}
console.log(temp);
```

try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < row.cells.lenght; i++) {
     temp = temp.replace(new RegExp("\\{"+i+"\\}", "g"), row.cells[0].innerText);
}
```